# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export(…)"

Tags: angular, systemjs, ngrx

That's driving me nuts. I am using angular2-quickstart as a starter project. I just added @ngrx/store, @ngrx/core and @ngrx/effects to the project. Now I am getting the error in the title. I don't know how to track the error down as I'm not getting a descriptive error:

```
(anonymous function)    @   (index):18
ZoneDelegate.invoke @   zone.js:192
Zone.run    @   zone.js:85
(anonymous function)    @   zone.js:451
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:225
Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:125
drainMicroTaskQueue @   zone.js:357
ZoneTask.invoke @   zone.js:297
```

Any ideas or references about resolving the cryptic errors SystemJS raises?

Comment: is this the complete stack trace? or are you missing something?

Comment: This is the complete error output I can see. It happens when I uncomment a line that imports store from ngrx: "import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';"

Comment: Can you try with the system config given here https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/67#issuecomment-196151894

Comment: @DeendayalGarg Thank you but this is solution is for an older version as there is no 'dist' folder under ngrx anymore. I now suspect that's something to do with ES6. When I comment out the export lines in ngrx/store/index the error goes away. I should probably ask this to ngrx guys on Github.

Comment: After 2 hours of hard work, I switched to webpack and all my problems are gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project just ran into the same thing. It would appear that @ngrx/core and @ngrx/store started using ES7 "export" statements in their javascript. These are not supported in any browser right now, and require a transpiler to work.

So, in order to restore your functionality, the first thing to do is to change your package.json to use an old, working version of @ngrx/*. This is of course not a long term solution, so in the long term, the options are one of the following:

- Use Babeljs (or similar) to make your compilation chain support ES7.
- Switch to Webpack and its loaders (as you have done), which are better at reliably outputting code that is standards-compliant. You appear to have done this already.
- Yell at a ngrx developer about who ever thought it was a good idea to include JS code that is not supported as JS by any browser, without announcing that you now need to do extra work for it.

Comment: I guess that's a constant issue with ngrx. Almost all of the examples (including their own) are outdated and need updates. It's been 3 days and I'm still struggling to create a working project :-)

Comment: Something that just occurred to me with regards to using Webpack: you might run into this issue again if you don't use a transpiler of some sort. Switching to Webpack worked because it replaces the (unsupported) `import` statements with its own requires (which are legal ES6/ES5). However, if the ngrx folks (or someone else) decided to use another ES7 feature, such as trailing commas in function arguments (e.g. `constructor(a: string, b: number,) {}`, your code would again fail to run. I'm not sure whether you can feed JS through the ts-loader, or need babel loader to fix this.

Comment: Wrong. "export" is a ES2015 feature. ngrx always distributes ES5, transpiled version. Just use bundles instead of the src/ directory (that contains ES5 code in ES2015 module syntax (to be clear, module syntax only, no other ES2015+ feature). Refer to bertrandg answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it loading `UMD modules` using this `systemjs` config:

```
System.config({
    map: {
      ...
      '@ngrx': 'node_modules/@ngrx',
    },
    package: {
      ...
      '@ngrx/core': { main: '/bundles/core.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      '@ngrx/store': { main: '/bundles/store.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      '@ngrx/effects': { main: '/bundles/effects.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      '@ngrx/store-devtools': { main: '/bundles/store-devtools.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      '@ngrx/store-log-monitor': { main: '/bundles/store-log-monitor.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    }
})
```

I'm using these version:

`core` 1.2.0 / `store` 2.2.1 / `effects` 2.0.0 / `store-devtools` 3.1.0 / `store-log-monitor` 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in systemjs.config.js:

```
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/'
},
map: {
  ...
  '@ngrx/core': 'npm:@ngrx/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@ngrx/store': 'npm:@ngrx/store/bundles/store.umd.js',
},
package: {
  ...
}
```

After this `import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';` is working.